# Google Visualization.Sankey -- GoogleScript Dropping Node Label

Tags: google-apps-script

[Removed by author closing their account]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion:

The reason why you are getting the cut image of the sankey graph is because of the `zero` values you have in `"D"`.
I have found a similar concern like this in git hub: [Node positions do not work with link value zero in Sankey](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2152)

I suggest that you remove `zeros` first by filtering the array:

**Modified code:**

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .createMenu('CustomScripts')
        .addItem('SankeyDiagram', 'openDialog')
        .addToUi();
}

function getSpreadsheetData() {
    // ID of your Document, take from URL
    var ssID = "1KtvAFFQV13zSwktXKtUXZLQF9hmb9VaxbC4OM3hGEVw",
        // which Sheet? [0] is the first and so on...
        sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
        data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
      ///Filtered the data by removing zeros
        header = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,3).getValues()[0],
        filteredData = data.filter(r => r[2] > 0);
        filteredData.unshift(header)
    return filteredData
}

function openDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setHeight(300)
        .setWidth(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .showModalDialog(html, 'Sankey Diagram');
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This (erratic) behavior is not documented elsewhere in Google's official documentations pertaining to Sankey charts. I had trouble making the chart in Looker Studio and fortunately ended up here after a long, unfruitful searching. Kudos to you, take my upvote.